# Upgrading to @mui/styles@5.13.2 requires a peer of react@^17?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Despite the documentation's assertion that React 18 should be all I need:
[image]
I am getting an error that says I need React 17:

> *@mui/styles@5.13.2 requires a peer of react@^17.0.0 but none is installed.*

This is the relevant bit in my `package.json` (unrelated packages not shown):

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/material": "^5.13.2",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.13.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
  },
```

I don't understand the requirement to have React 17 when the docs clearly state that 18 is supported.  Someone make it make sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the following `@mui/styles` documentation.

https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

> `@mui/styles` is the **legacy** styling solution for Material UI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the `@mui/material` anymore, deprecated in v5. If you don't want to have both Emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the `@mui/system` documentation which is the recommended alternative.

> `@mui/styles` is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.